# Associatedtype does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a generic registration system. I created a structure like below.

```swift
public protocol LBRegisterable: AnyObject {
    associatedtype CustomRegisterDelegate: LBRegisterDelegate
    var delegate: CustomRegisterDelegate? {get set}
    func doRegister()
}
```

All registration steps must inherit this protocol. The `doRegister()` method is used to complete the current register step.

The `CustomRegisterDelegate` is created to communicate with the view controller. When the current registration step is completed, each registering class informs the view controller the result with this delegate. Since this result declaration method will be in every delegate class, it was created in the protocol named `LBRegisterDelegate`.

```swift
public protocol LBRegisterDelegate: AnyObject {
    func registerResult(from: LBRegisterStepType, result: LBRegisterResult)
}
```

My problem here is that this build throws an error. I hope you will understand the situation better when you review the example below.

Photo Choose Step Classes :

```swift
public protocol LBRegisterPhotoStepViewDelegate: AnyObject, LBRegisterDelegate {
    func choosePhotoRequestReceived(from: LBRegisterPhotoStepView)
}
```

The user has to select an image. When a button is clicked, this delegate notifies the view controller.

```swift
public class LBRegisterPhotoStepView: LBView, LBRegisterable {    
    public typealias CustomRegisterDelegate = LBRegisterPhotoStepViewDelegate
    public var delegate: LBRegisterPhotoStepViewDelegate?
    
    public func doRegister() { }
}
```

`CustomRegisterDelegate` was an associated type and had to inherit from the `LBregisterDelegate` protocol. The `LBregisterPhotoStepViewDelegate` protocol I gave in this section does not work.

[image: errorImage]

Where am I doing wrong? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `LBRegisterPhotoStepViewDelegate` is a protocol and I'd say `CustomRegisterDelegate` should be a concrete type not a protocol.

Comment: This protocol doesn't make a lot of sense. I can't picture any way that a caller could use it. Can you show an example of the code duplication you're having (with concrete types)? From there, I think the protocol (if any is needed), will be clear. It's particularly not clear why CustomRegisterDelegate exists. That seems unnecessary. The error itself is straight-forward: protocols never conform to protocols. A protocol cannot be used as the conformance for an associated type. The associated type must be filled in with a concrete type. (But it's not clear how in this case the types are useful.)

Answer (score 0):

Making `LBRegisterPhotoStepView` generic and introducing the corresponding associated type to `LBRegisterPhotoStepViewDelegate` can make this relationship work:

```swift
protocol LBRegisterPhotoStepViewDelegate: LBRegisterDelegate {

  associatedtype Delegate: LBRegisterPhotoStepViewDelegate

  func choosePhotoRequestReceived(from: LBRegisterPhotoStepView<Delegate>)  

}

class LBRegisterPhotoStepView<Delegate: LBRegisterPhotoStepViewDelegate>: LBRegisterable {

  var delegate: Delegate?

  func doRegister() { }  

}
```